# QGIS Breaks Vector file when Projected

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-layer

I am using QGIS3.4 and I am running into an unexpected problem. I have received a gdb file, the file looks fine in WGS 84 projection. But when I use any other, the polygons seems to be cut strangely.

[image: Example of of it is broken is here]

Does anyone know how to solve this without changing the vector file with a different world map.

Comment: Which projection do you reproject your layer to? That projection may not be useable for the whole globe. If you use QGIS 3 you can see the valid area of projections.

Comment: Have you tried saving the file in a different projection?

Comment: I tried almost every possible projection. The one I posted was Sphere_Van_der_Grinten_I which I have used without problem before.